# Group By query in MySQL not working properly

Tags: mysql, group-by

I make a query to find the last 24 results from three different tables.

The query is :

```
SELECT m.MovID,m.Type,m.Image,m.Date,t.SerID,t.Type,t.Image,t.Date,g.GamID,g.Type,g.Image,g.Date
FROM movie m, tvseries t, games g
GROUP BY m.MovID, t.SerID, g.GamID
LIMIT  0,24
```

but in the result of this query  **group by** is not working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and sample result you're trying to get from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` is not the problem (at least not the major one).

Th real problem is that you selecting data from 3 tables **without** joining them. This part of your query:

```
from   movie m
       , tvseries t
       , games g
```

meanss all combinations of every row of the 1st table with every row of the 2nd with every row of the 3rd table. Is that what you want?

```
FROM   movie m
  CROSS JOIN  tvseries t
  CROSS JOIN  games g
```

---

Most probably you want to `JOIN` the 3 tables:

```
FROM   movie m
  INNER JOIN  tvseries t
    ON  t.someColumn = m.someColumn 
  INNER JOIN  games g 
    ON  g.someOtherColumn = m.someOtherColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

All columns that appear in `SELECT` should either:

1. be present also in `GROUP BY` part of statement OR
2. be computed by some aggregate function like `SUM`, `AVG` etc.

Comment: This is wrong with regards to MySQL. See the comments on gdoron's answer.

Comment: @Lieven: Thanks for the tip, I've already checked the MySQL documentation. Can't say it's a good idea to use undeterminate data and I don't think OP actually wants this... Anyway, that's why OP's query was not rejected by server even though it violates standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information about what is wrong with your query or what results you are expecting Vs. what you are receiving, I think that you should include `m.MovID` in you `SELECT` . It is best practice to `GROUP BY` what you `SELECT` and to `SELECT` what you `GROUP BY`.